# With SQL Server, How can I query a table based on a delimited string as the criteria?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

**tbl_File**:

```
FileID | Filename
-----------------
1      | test.jpg
```

and

**tbl_Tag**:

```
TagID | TagName
---------------
1     | Red
```

and

**tbl_TagFile**:

```
ID | TagID | FileID
-------------------
1  | 1     | 1
```

I need to pass a non-inclusive query against these tables. For example, imagine a list of checkboxes to select one or more tags, and then a search button. I need to pass the TagID's to the query as a PIPE delimited string, such as "1|2|5|"

The search results need to be non-inclusive, such as if it must meet all the criteria. If 3 tags are selected, the results are to be files that have all 3 tags associated with them.

I think I've made this too complicated, but tried iterating over the tags using charindex and stuff to work my way through the string, but it seems there must be an easier way.

I'd like to do this as a function... Such as

```
SELECT FileID, Filename 
FROM tbl_Files 
WHERE dbo.udf_FileExistswithTags(@Tags, FileID) = 1
```

Any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Consider using table-valued parameters for this. This way you just pass a whole table from the client and the server can manage it like any other table in a set-based form and eliminates the need to do complicated text parsing in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option that should scale. All of the functionality is available back to SQL Server 2005. It uses a CTE to separate the portion of the query that finds only the `FileID`s that have *all* of the `TagID`s passed in, and then that list of `FileID`s is joined to the `[File]` table to get the details. It also uses an `INNER JOIN` instead of an `IN` list to match the TagID's.

Please note that the example below uses a SQLCLR splitter that is freely available in the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I wrote, but this function is in the Free version). The specific splitter used is not the important part; it should just be one that is either SQLCLR, an inline tally-table (like the one used in @wewesthemenace's answer), or is the XML method. Just don't use a splitter based on a WHILE-loop or a recursive CTE.

```sql
---- TEST SETUP
DECLARE @File TABLE
(
  FileID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Filename] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @TagFile TABLE
(
  TagID INT NOT NULL,
  FileID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (TagID, FileID)
);

INSERT INTO @File VALUES (1, 'File1.txt');
INSERT INTO @File VALUES (2, 'File2.txt');
INSERT INTO @File VALUES (3, 'File3.txt');

INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (5, 1);
INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (5, 3);
INSERT INTO @TagFile VALUES (6, 3);
---- DONE WITH TEST SETUP

DECLARE @TagsToGet VARCHAR(100); -- this would be the proc input parameter
SET @TagsToGet = '1|2|5';

CREATE TABLE #Tags (TagID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
DECLARE @NumTags INT;

INSERT INTO #Tags (TagID)
  SELECT split.SplitVal
  FROM   SQL#.String_Split4k(@TagsToGet, '|', 1) split;

SET @NumTags = @@ROWCOUNT;

;WITH files AS
(
  SELECT  tf.FileID
  FROM    @TagFile tf
  INNER JOIN #Tags tg
          ON tg.TagID = tf.TagID
  GROUP BY tf.FileID
  HAVING   COUNT(*) = @NumTags
)
SELECT fl.*
FROM   @File fl
INNER JOIN files
        ON files.FileID = fl.FileID
ORDER BY fl.[Filename] ASC;

DROP TABLE #Tags; -- don't need this if code above is placed in a proc
```

Results:

```
FileID   Filename
1        File1.txt
3        File3.txt
```

---

**Notes**

- As much as I love TVPs (and I do, when they are done correctly and used appropriately), I would say that they are a bit much for this type of small scale, single dimensional array scenario. There won't really be any performance gain over using a SQLCLR streaming TVF string splitter but it would require more app code and the additional User-Defined Table Type, which can't be updated without first dropping all procs that reference it. That doesn't happen all of the time, but needs to be considered in terms of long-term maintenance costs.
- The JOIN between `TagFile` and the temporary table populated from the split operation should be much more efficient than using an `IN` list with a subquery for the split operation. An `IN` list is short-hand for all of the values in it to be their own OR conditions. Hence the JOIN is a fully set-based approach that lets the Query Optimizer do its thang.
- The structure I used for the test `@TagFile` table only has the two relevant IDs in it: `TagID` and `FileID`. It does not have the `ID` field that I assume is an IDENTITY field on this table. Unless there is a very specific reason for needing that IDENTITY field, I would suggest removing it. It adds to inherent benefit as the combination of `TagID` and `FileID` *is* a natural key (i.e. it is both NOT NULL and Unique). And if the Clustered PK of this table were simply those two fields, the JOIN to the temp table of those split-out TagIDs would be quite fast, even with millions of rows in `TagFile`.
- One reason that this approach works so much better than trying to handle this via a function per `FileID` (outside of the obvious set-based is better than cursor-based reason) is that the list of `TagID`s is the same for all files to be checked. So splitting that out more than one time is a waste of effort.
- By not splitting the TagID list inline in the query I am able to capture the number of elements in that list with no additional effort. Hence this saves from needing to do a secondary calculation.

Comment: This is more efficient than my own answer, obviously, and was the easiest to understand and implement. I'm still exploring the other answers but I love the straight forward approach here.

Comment: Reading notes now, and up-vote completed. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't sound from your example scenario that the actual "need" is to pass a pipe-delimited string. I would highly suggest abandoning that idea and using a Table Value Parameter in your stored procedure.  This has numerous advantages in that you will not hit a datatype limit or a "number of parameters" limit that might occur with very large sets of criteria.  Additionally it gets away from any need to run a (potentially very slow) UDF.

Split the string into tokens on the application side, and then insert each token as a row in the TVP. Example below:

Create the TVP type in your database:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[FileNameType] AS TABLE
(
    fileName varchar(1000)
)
```

On the application side, build your list of filename tokens into a recordset:

```
private static List<SqlDataRecord> BuildFileNameTokenRecords(IEnumerable<string> tokens)
        {
            var records = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
            foreach (string token in tokens){
var record = new SqlDataRecord(
                    new SqlMetaData[]
                    {
                        new SqlMetaData("fileName", SqlDbType.Varchar),
                    }
                );
                records.Add(record);
            }
            return records;
        }
```

Wherever you run your proc from (rough code here):

```
var records = BuildFileNameTokenRecords(listofstrings);
var sqlCmd = sqlDb.GetStoredProcCommand("FileExists");
sqlDb.AddInParameter(sqlCmd, "tvpFilenameTokens", SqlDbType.Structured, records);
ExecuteNonQuery(sqlCmd);
```

Filtering your select statement then simply becomes a matter of joining on the tokens in the table parameter.  Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FileExists
    (
     -- Put additional parameters here
     @tvpFilenameTokens dbo.FileNameType READONLY,
    )
    AS
BEGIN
    SELECT FileID, Filename 
    FROM tbl_Files INNER JOIN @tvpFilenameTokens
    ON tbl_Files.FileID = @tvpFilenameTokens.fileName 
END
```

Comment: I can't pass a table valued parameter to the sp. I suppose I could create a dynamic table with the delimited string? What do you think?

Comment: I was thinking of a function in the event that no criteria is passed... as in WHERE (dbo.udf_FileExistswithTags(@Tags, FileID) = 1 OR isnull(@Tags, '') = '')

Comment: Creating a dynamic table is certainly an option.  You risk consistency issues if it's outside of a sessional context though.  The primary goal would be to do the string parsing outside of SQL Server as most non-SQL languages are much better suited to it, and then simplifying your filter criteria with that set of tokens in SQL.

Comment: Using a UDF in a WHERE clause can have severe performance penalties.  If that is the route you go you should be sure to test with a lot of data.

Comment: TVP's only work in 2008+. If you're using 2005 or earlier then TVP is no good

Comment: Not using C# for the application side.

Comment: @user1447679 and womp: not only are TVPs _probably_ overkill at this scale, but this is an inefficient approach to TVPs to begin with. First, the method returns `List<SqlDataRecord>` instead of `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`. This means you duplicate the collection in order to pass it in rather than simply iterating through it (i.e. true streaming). Second, `var record = new SqlDataRecord()` is called inside of the `foreach` loop when it should be done once just before the loop. Of course, passing in filenames will not help solve this, but I thought I would mention this could be more efficient.

Comment: womp, @user1447679 , and anyone else who might be interested: I have posted the revised code on PasteBin.com. I started with womp's code as the basis and made the necessary adjustments. http://pastebin.com/bbQScyTq (expires in 30 days)

Comment: Glad it helped even if it wasn't your ultimate solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function called `DelimitedSplit8K` by Jeff Moden. This is used to split strings of length up to 8000. For more info, read this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](
    @pString    VARCHAR(8000), --WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
    @pDelimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

WITH E1(N) AS (--10E+1 or 10 rows
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS (
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString, t.N, 1) = @pDelimiter
),
cteLen(N1, L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
    SELECT 
        s.N1,
        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pString, s.N1), 0) - s.N1, 8000)
    FROM cteStart s
)
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
SELECT 
    ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
    Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
FROM cteLen l
```

Your query would now be:

```
DECLARE @pString VARCHAR(8000) = '1|3|5'

SELECT
    f.*
FROM tbl_File f
INNER JOIN tbl_TagFile tf ON tf.FileID = f.FileID
WHERE
    tf.TagID IN(SELECT CAST(item AS INT) FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@pString, '|'))
GROUP BY f.FileID, f.FileName
HAVING COUNT(tf.ID) = (LEN(@pString) - LEN(REPLACE(@pString,'|','')) + 1)
```

The statement below counts the number of `TagID` in the parameter by counting the occurrence of the delimiter `|` + 1.

```
(LEN(@pString) - LEN(REPLACE(@pString,'|','')) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that does not require UDF's.

It can be argued that this is also complicated.

```
DECLARE @TagList VARCHAR(50)

-- pass in this
SET @TagList = '1|3|6'

SELECT
FinalSet.FileID, 
FinalSet.Tag,
FinalSet.TotalMatches
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    tbl_TagFile.FileID, 
    tbl_TagFile.Tag,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY tbl_TagFile.FileID) TotalMatches
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 1 FileID, '1' Tag  UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 , '2'  UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 , '3'  UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 , '6'  UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 , '1'  UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 , '3'
    ) tbl_TagFile
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT tbl_Tag.Tag
        FROM 
        (
        SELECT '1' Tag  UNION ALL
        SELECT '2' UNION ALL
        SELECT '3' UNION ALL
        SELECT '4' UNION ALL
        SELECT '5' UNION ALL
        SELECT '6' 
        ) tbl_Tag
        WHERE '|' + @TagList + '|' LIKE '%|' + Tag + '|%'
    ) LimitedTagTable
    ON LimitedTagTable.Tag = tbl_TagFile.Tag
) FinalSet
WHERE   
FinalSet.TotalMatches = (LEN(@TagList) - LEN(REPLACE(@TagList,'|','')) + 1)
```

There's some complications in this around data types and indexes and stuff but you can see the concept - you are only getting the records that match your passed in string.

subtable `LimitedTagTable` is your tag list filtered by your input pipe delimited string

subtable `FinalSet` joins your limited tag list to your list of files

column `TotalMatches` works out how many tag matches your file had

Finally this line limits the output to those files that had enough matches:

```
FinalSet.TotalMatches = (LEN(@TagList) - LEN(REPLACE(@TagList,'|','')) + 1)
```

Please experiment with different inputs and datasets and see if it suits as I have made a number of assumptions.

Comment: This is interesting. Could you clarify a bit more with a brief example, or a bit more elaborate than what you already posted? I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Have a try and post back any questions. If this works for you, it's important to note that the tag filtering is based on a LIKE string that uses a non sargeable search (a LIKE starting with a %), which means you cannot build an index to speed up the tag filtering. This can a big issue with a LOT of tags. Oh the `COUNT(*) OVER` keyword requires a specific version of SQL Server - please add your version to the question tags

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question, in hopes that someone can let me know if/how flawed it is. So far it seems to be working but just early testing.

Function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_FileExistsByTags]
(
     @FileID int
    ,@Tags nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Exists bit = 0
    DECLARE @Count int = 0
    DECLARE @TagTable TABLE ( FileID int, TagID int )
    DECLARE @Tag int

    WHILE len(@Tags) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Tag = CAST(LEFT(@Tags, charindex('|', @Tags + '|') -1) as int)
        SET @Count = @Count + 1
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_FileTag WHERE FileID = @FileID AND TagID = @Tag )
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @TagTable ( FileID, TagID ) VALUES ( @FileID, @Tag )
            END
        SET @Tags = STUFF(@Tags, 1, charindex('|', @Tags + '|'), '')
    END

    SET @Exists = CASE WHEN @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TagTable) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    RETURN @Exists

END
```

Then in the query:

SELECT * FROM tbl_File a WHERE dbo.udf_FileExistsByTags(a.FileID, @Tags) = 1

So now I'm looking for errors.

What do you think? Probably not every efficient, however this search will be used only on a periodic basis.

Comment: This won't scale well. Which means it might take 10 seconds for 1,000 file records and 10,000 tag records, and take 1 day for 10,000 file records and 100,000 tag records. Just consider what kind of data growth you are expecting.

Comment: Oh and keep in mind this is a procedural (in databases = slow) solution vs a set based solution (no loops, if/then or variables)